# Проверка закрытия тегов HTML

Tags: php, laravel

Всем привет. Можете подсказать что-то. 
Мне с клиента приходит какой-то текст. В этом тексте есть теги. Нужно как-то проверить теги на закрытие, а также на атрибуты, например,  **alt** в теге **a**.
Кто-то может сталкивался с такой задачей.

Comment: Можно эту проверку делать используя [W3C API](https://validator.w3.org/docs/api.html)

Answer (score 0):

Используйте DOM, парсите и проверяйте атрибуты. Это самый надёжный способ на данный момент по моему мнению.